# Ionic Inappbrowser to picking up exit event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

My app which is built on ionic has an inapp browser that opens a url. This works fine.
I need to identify when and if the user clicks the close/"X" button on it to run a function.

I have tried the exit eventlistener but it is not fired when the browser is closed.

I have tried the below.

```
var ref = window.open($scope.url, '_blank');
```

then

```
ref.addEventListener('exit', $scope.bclose());
    $scope.bclose = function(){
        alert('Close');
    }
```

also

```
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { 
   alert('Browser Closed');
});
```

I however have a loadstop listener which works fine.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use following way. It is working fine.

```
 $scope.openLink = function (url) {

        var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');

        ref.addEventListener('exit', function(){
         alert('exit');
        });

    }
```

I am using following cordova inappbrowser version in my config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" src="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git" version="1.4.1-dev" />
```

Comment: Hi..thanks this works. Is there anyway I can get the url the browser was on. I tried ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event){
  alert(event.url);
        }); but I get undefined.

Comment: use, `ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event){ alert(event.url); }); `   . this was worked for me.

Comment: So in other words, the exit listener doesn't give out the url? We have to use the loadstart listener to monitor and record the url in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

try this:- 
 when you open it in _self the state management of the app is handled.

`$` `scope.openLink = function (url) {`

```
    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_self', 'location=yes');

    ref.addEventListener('exit', function(){
     alert('exit');
    });

}
```